# Manual ECU with Automatic Car

Tags: automatic-transmission, computer

Have 92 Accord with 1.8 VTEC. The Installed Engine is From 98 Accord. The transmission is the original which came with 92 accord. This transmission is operated by Kick Down cable and does not have any Main Shaft or Counter Shaft Sensors.

During Swap My Car was Given ODB2B Engine hence ECU was replaced. As car had its on TCU so transmission kept working great and is still working flawlessly.

The ECU Installed expects to have Main Shaft and Counter Shaft Speed Sensor attached where as I do not have them. I was thinking that why not install a Manual ECU so that VTEC should work and As existing ECU is not getting any signal so on pressing throttle in D ECU thinks of Slipping.

Would Manual ECU work in my current Setup?

Comment: Seriously No ONE?

Comment: Its holiday time - Christmas and New Year will probably account for lack of responses.

Comment: Are you sure your new (to you) engine came out of an Accord, or its a 98? I cannot find this option listed anywhere while doing research on your question. You positive it's a 1.8l? I only see a 2.3l 4-cylinder available for the 98 Accord. Then again, there might be more options available to you considering you are international (from my standpoint).

Comment: Well in US there were above 2.0 but this is JDM Engine. Its model is F18B and came in Accords 96-2000

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your '92 transmission is not operated by an ECU. The kick down cable and in-built governor decide the change points of the transmission, using line and governor pressures.

The engine that you have now had fitted would come under OBD2 because of its time of production,'98. The variable valve operation would use signals from a later transmission, which you do not have fitted, as part of OBD2 control.

You need to have '92 engine and transmission, or, '98 engine and transmission to have a single ECU controlling the installation.

The '92 ECU will have inputs, sensors, wiring and software for the '92 set-up. The '98 ECU will have inputs, sensors, wiring and software for the '98 set-up. There will always be differences between the two and they will always be incompatable.

Comment: He's asking about using an 98 ECU from a manual shift vehicle to replace the one which is programmed for an automatic. It's not about the control, but about not having the ECU think there is an issue with the transmission and pop codes or cause the engine to run differently because of non input from the transmission which it will never get. Please consider updating your post accordingly as it in no way attempts to answer the question at hand. Also remember he's in Pakistan, so probably won't have a tuner shop available to reprogram the ECU.

Comment: @Paulster2 exactly. In our country there comes no new parts for these accords also no mods or custom stuff. If you ask shop keeper about anything different he stares at you as if you have asked him to donate his kidneys........

Comment: The 92 transmission does not have an ECU to operate. The 98 transmission has an input to allow variable valve operation for emissions and cruising.

Comment: @AllanOsborne ... Please reread what I said. You are not comprehending the question. The OP states he knows all that. Your answer adds nothing to his knowledge, nor does it answer the question. His question, in basic form is, if he uses the 98 ECU from a STANDARD shift vehicle (same to his current ECU in all other respects), will it eliminate his issues. He doesn't have a 98 transmission, nor does he need one, the 92 transmission is working great. He does not have access to a tuner, so cannot tune out the issue.

Comment: @AfnanBashir ... For an entrepreneurial person, this could be an area a person could make some money, if you ask me. You could be the GodFather of mods in Pakistan!

Comment: @Paulster2 very good idea. What do you think i should start from ?

Comment: Since I bought this car I had done extreme wiring and restored this car to fully functional form. I was forced to do this as even best guys here said "This is a lot of alteration done. It is impossible to sort out"

Comment: @AfnanBashir ... start with what you know and expand from there. Obtain the tools you will need (doing this as your skills improve is the most practical way). Read the forums for the types of vehicles you want to work on. What type of vehicle is most prevalent in Pakistan? Do what you can and stand by your work. Don't over commit. Good Luck!